# How do I remove the next elemen from $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with jQuery and found some issue. I have a button that will add a `label` and a `span` when clicked. But when I'm trying to remove the labels by clicking it one by one, the span with comma is not removed. I'd like to remove the span after the clicked label. Here's my script.

```
$('#btn_add_vendor').on('click', function(){
    var added = "<label class='label label-primary lbl_test'>MY LABEL</label><span class='add_comma'>,</span>";

    $('#div_label').append(added); //the label appended here, in a div.

    $('.lbl_test').click(function () {
       $(this).remove();
       $(this).next(".add_comma").remove(); //not working

    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried first removing the ".add-comma" and the the element itselves ? And can you provide the html ?

Comment: I think it should be `$(this).nextUntil('.add_comma').next().remove();`

Comment: $(this).closest(".add_comma").remove();

Comment: @BarentBoden the html is already there

Comment: @smit I mean the rest of the html, if you run this it wont work and my name is BrentBoden

Comment: @BrentBoden .add_comma can be removed. What I am looking for is to remove .add_comma which placed after the specifc label is clicked

Comment: @ashura91 I was saying if you remove $(this) first, the reference to $(this) will not exist anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove `$(this)`first, the reference to `$(this)` will not exist anymore.
Try to change the order and do it like this:

```
$('.lbl_test').click(function () {
   $(this).next(".add_comma").remove();
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: I just commented the same xd

Comment: Didn't see it before I posted. Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: just because its a little mistake but i upvoted yours instead so.

Comment: Thank you.  How about removing previous span?

Comment: Thanks, @BrentBoden!

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because when you removed the label then span will not found as its next element. And also use document on click method as the elements are dynamic appended.

Please change you code to following:

```
$('#btn_add_vendor').on('click', function(){
    var added = "<label class='label label-primary lbl_test'>MY LABEL</label><span class='add_comma'>,</span>";

    $('#div_label').append(added); //the label appended here, in a div.

    $(document).on("click",".lbl_test",function () {

       $(this).next(".add_comma").remove(); //REMOVE span FIRST
       $(this).remove();//THEN REMOVE label
    });
});
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

remove the span before removing `$('.lbl_test')` .

```
$('#btn_add_vendor').on('click', function(){
var added = "<label class='label label-primary lbl_test'>MY LABEL</label><span class='add_comma'>,</span>";

$('#div_label').append(added); 
  $('.lbl_test').click(function () {
     $(this).next(".add_comma").remove(); 
     $(this).remove();
   });
});
```